# Set opacity to the menu but keep text opaque in CSS

Tags: css, transparency, opacity, rgba

How can I create a menu which only its background is transparent? The text should keep opaque (opacity: 1)

If I set

```
li:hover {
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

The whole list item becomes transparent. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a new value in CSS3 called "rgba" that allows you to use a transparent color as a background color. For instance:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

I'm fairly sure that should work, though I just wrote the code on the spot so it may not. This will, however, give your menu a white-ish tinge to it. If you want to read more about RGBA, though, go here: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: This is the easiest solution, but missing IE and FF2 support are *big* downsides

Comment: For OP: Be aware that CSS3 isn't compatible with all browsers yet. If that doesn't bother you, this is a great answer.

Comment: There is, actually, a hack that allows an RGBA-like effect for Internet Explorer using the "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient" property that Microsoft made. There's more information about it in the article I linked to. I don't know about FF2, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The transparency level gets handed down to all child elements.

Your options:

- Place another element on top of the `li`, possibly using `position: absolute`, that has a normal opacity setting
- Use a PNG file with Alpha transparency to create the opacity effect (Will need workarounds to work in IE6)
- Use the new `rgba` colour property as shown by @hatkirby, if you can live with the incomplete browser support

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to use either a transparent PNG image, or an [`rgba` colour value](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/), for the `<li>`’s background, e.g.:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Or:

```
li:hover {
    background: url(a-nice-semi-transparent-png-image.png);

    /* Supplying just the image file here will make the browser repeat the image
    file vertically and horizontally, thus taking up all the space, just like a 
    colour would */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that's possible, try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/578SV/